# License that grants free use for non commercial purposes but asks for some money for commercial use

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation

I have developed material to teach a programming class. It is an old style class, thought for a teacher teaching to students, with slides and examples.
The material is made of a website, where the slides for the instructor are available, and of examples and tests.

I would like to make this material freely accessible to anyone who wants to use it for non commercial purposes. Instead, if there is someone who wants to use it with commercial purposes (e.g. a company that sells education services), I would like to be contacted first to agree on a certain sum of money to use it. Such money would then be devolved to non profit organizations.

s there an "open-source" type of license that fits with this scenario?

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT if I understand right, the answer covers the case of software. In my case the core of the material are the slides of the course. I have read somewhere else that "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike (CC BY-NC-SA) license" could be a good fit. What is your opinion. Thanks anyways in advance.

Comment: You were asking for "open source" licenses, which as a basic principle would not discriminate between commercial and non-commercial use. [CC BY-NC-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/legalcode) it might be a good fit for you, but it is off-topic here.

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT thanks a lot. I was not aware that this is off topic for this forum. Thanks anyways